# How to run electron app by supervisor?

Tags: electron, supervisord

We developed a app which runs on kiosks for products sale. In the past, the app was started by firefox 44.0.4 pre-installed in the kiosk, but it has so many issues so we have to find an alternative. After searching, electron seems good and we have our code running successfully by it.

In order to ensure our app never crash or stop by accident, we have used supervisor to run the firefox. When we tried to run electron, it failed, here are supervisor logs:

```
2016-08-08 10:49:06,337 INFO spawned: 'x1ux' with pid 3903
2016-08-08 10:49:06,439 INFO exited: x1ux (exit status 1; not expected)
2016-08-08 10:49:07,441 INFO gave up: x1ux entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly
```

Here is our config file for the app:

```
[program:x1ux]
command = /home/f1/electron/ntt/src
process_name = x1ux
autostart = true
startsecs = 3
autorestart = true
user = f1
redirect_stderr = true
stdout_logfile = /tmp/x1ux.log
stderr_logfile = /tmp/x1ux.log
```

FYI: the os is ubuntu 14.04 x64
Here is my question: **How to run electron apps by supervisor?Or what is the right way to run an electron app forever?**

Comment: Did you ever figured this out? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I figured out something that worked for me. It turns out that it was an issue with X Windows not allowing electron to [set up a connection to it](https://github.com/jessfraz/dockerfiles/issues/6). I simply had to run

```
xhost local:root
```

and it started working. I also noticed that you don't have the `DISPLAY` environment variable being set in your supervisor config file. You probably want to add something like this:

```
[program:x1ux]
command = /home/f1/electron/ntt/src
...
environment=DISPLAY=':0'
```

To be honest, I don't know much about X Windows or really why the `xhost` command is required here but as soon as I figured that out I'll post an update.